Black screen after installing 24.04 LTS
I have an MSI B450M Pro VDH MAX with a Ryzen 3700X, 16GB RAM, Nvidia GTX 1070 and 1TB NVME drive + a bunch of HDD. It works with Windows 10 as a fileserver. I disconnected the HDD's and tried to install 24.04 LTS on the system via USB stick (created via Rufus in iso mode).
I could boot the live version, but only in low graphic mode. I choose install and additional drivers and I selected the suggested NVIDIA driver. Everything installed without any error message. But after reboot I get only the MSI Splash screen with the Ubuntu Logo and then a black screen. I have no other card and like I said a Win10 install works without problems.
I tried an older version of Ubuntu (18.04) too and the result was the same. Booting via a USB rescue system in both cases showed that the NVME was formatted with ext4 and a small fat32 partition and had the boot flag. Any idea what to do to get a working desktop / login screen?

Wrong video driver.

Yes, could be video driver. When you say "suggested nvidia driver", do you refer to the propietary one?I also isntalled ubuntu 24.04, but following normal installation not safe graphics; chose all additional features like propietary drivers and didn't have problems. In my experience using different linux distros and nvidia gpus, xorg almost always is faulty or functional but with severe defects and limitations. By contrast, nvidia latest propietary drivers worked almost perfectly 90% of the time.

About other possibilities...it might be a faulty boot process. When you were at installation screen, did you choose erase all disk and install ubuntu, install next to windows or performed a custom partition table?Additionally, what do you exactly see at rebooting?Msi logo, then ubuntu's, then black screen...or at some point you see the grub menu?

I erased the nvme - I wanted to make sure there is nothing left of windows. I did not see the grub menu... Just the when the system boot there is the MSI logo and a bit down was always the turning circle from windows when booting now instead of the circle there the Ubuntu logo slowly blinking until the screen gets black. The install offered four or five drivers and one (propietary) was recommended and I choose that, but using one of the others did not help with the problem after install. Next weekend I will try to install the system without graphis and then install the rest by hand.
